# Multiple tables, same column, using where

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems with this query.  It returns correct total_names, total_events, and total_misc, but the other three totals (pending names, events, and misc) are the same number and totally the wrong number.  All three tables have the created_by column.  What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT names_revisions.id) AS total_names,
    COUNT(DISTINCT events_revisions.id) AS total_events,
    COUNT(DISTINCT misc_revisions.id) AS total_misc,
    SUM(if(names_revisions.status = "Pending", 1, 0)) AS total_pending_names, 
    SUM(if(events_revisions.status = "Pending", 1, 0)) AS total_pending_events, 
    SUM(if(misc_revisions.status = "Pending", 1, 0)) AS total_pending_misc
FROM 
    names_revisions,
    events_revisions,
    misc_revisions
WHERE 
    :user_id IN (names_revisions.created_by, events_revisions.created_by, misc_revisions.created_by)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the tables instead of just selecting the counts separately. It will be faster to use separate queries for the 3 tables instead of joins

```
SELECT
    names.total as toal_names,
    names.pending as total_pending_names,
    misc.total as total_misc,
    misc.pending as total_pending_misc,
    events.total as total_events,
    events.pending as total_pending_events
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(names_revisions.id) AS total,
            SUM(if(names_revisions.status = "Pending", 1, 0)) AS pending
        FROM names_revisions
        WHERE names_revisions.created_by = :user_id
    ) as names,
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(misc_revisions.id) AS total,
            SUM(if(misc_revisions.status = "Pending", 1, 0)) AS pending
        FROM misc_revisions
        WHERE misc_revisions.created_by = :user_id
    ) as misc,
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(events_revisions.id) AS total,
            SUM(if(events_revisions.status = "Pending", 1, 0)) AS pending
        FROM events_revisions
        WHERE events_revisions.created_by = :user_id
    ) as events
```

Comment: I like this method more since it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The `IN()` clause won't work the way you are attempting to use it.  You'll need `JOIN` conditions between your three tables, and then three `<table> = :user_id` in your `WHERE`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT names_revisions.id) AS total_names,
    COUNT(DISTINCT events_revisions.id) AS total_events,
    COUNT(DISTINCT misc_revisions.id) AS total_misc,
    SUM(if(names_revisions.status = "Pending", 1, 0)) AS total_pending_names, 
    SUM(if(events_revisions.status = "Pending", 1, 0)) AS total_pending_events, 
    SUM(if(misc_revisions.status = "Pending", 1, 0)) AS total_pending_misc
FROM 
    names_revisions,
    JOIN events_revisions ON names_revisions.created_by = events_revisions.created
    JOIN misc_revisions ON names_revisions.created_by = misc_revisions.created
WHERE 
  names_revisions.created_by = :user_id
  OR events_revisions.created_by = :user_id
  OR misc_revisions.created_by = :user_id
```